# Is this function complex differentiable?

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, cauchy-riemann-equations

Suppose $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$, where $z=x+iy$, for $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$. If u and v are real functions which are differentiable at all $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Then either show that it follows that $f(z)$ is differentiable as a function $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ or find a counterexample.

My first thought is that $f$ is differentiable and to use the Cauchy Reimann equations. However, I'm a little stuck and would appreciate any help. My logic is that if u and v are real and differentiable then they are continuous and the partial derivatives exist. It follows that the partial derivatives of $f$ exist. However, how do we know if the partial derivatives are continuous let alone whether or not the Cauchy Reimann equations hold?

Comment: If a mathematician cannot manage to find a proof, they try to find a counterexample. ;-)

Comment: $u(x,y)=x$, $v(x,y)=0$. Did you even tried to find a counterexample?

Comment: @jjagmath I did but I just assumed my work was wrong or I was looking at things wrong because it felt too easy.

Comment: **Riemann** please!  [Georg Friedrich Bernhard Riemann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernhard_Riemann).

Comment: @MartinR Glad to see that I am not the only one affected by this.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: It makes me cringe when I see “Reimann” or “Cauchy Schwartz” :) I really wonder where that comes from, there are hundreds of postings with those typos.